# iOS: UIWebView: strange behaviour: high latency on tap over <div>

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, delay

Have: iOS 7.x, iPad, UIWebView.

I show HTML+JavaScript in UIWebView. The target is to allow user tapping on some HTML page elements and making their decisions through it.

User sees HTML in UIWebView -> User taps options they like -> Options checked retrieved from UIWebView -> and processed...

I use this HTML code for tappable elements:

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%" onclick="this.addOrRemoveClass('selected'); redirect('pivot://reference?competency=3')">3 Communicates Instructional Needs</div>
```

and the following JavaScript code to make them highlighted on tap and deselected on the subsequent tap:

```
function redirect(url) {
    location.href = url;
}

Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + this.className + ' ');
}

Element.prototype.addOrRemoveClass = function (className) {
    if (!this.hasClass(className)) {
        this.className = className;
    }
    else {
        this.className = '';
    }
}

function redirect(url) {
    location.href = url;
}
```

**The problem is:** when I tap on that "tappable"  it first highlights it with some "default" color (somewhat grey) and only then highlights it with my color.

WHAT IS MORE ANNOYING: there is half-a-second to second delay between TAP event and highlighting applied.

Who knows workarounds or can just explain what is it?

Thanks!

Comment: Use ontouchstart (+ontouchend) combo instead of click to prevent "ghost click" (which is 300ms).

Comment: @zvona Thank you. Really helped. BUT I've encountered an issue. When you scroll web view - you get side-effect - "selectable" DIVs become selected. One DIV per scroll gesture. Could you, please, help with workaround?

Comment: so you activate the "selected" ontouchstart? You should apply it when ontouchend is triggered on the same element that dispatched ontouchstart event. Otherwise if a) view is scrolled or b) finger is moved, then nothing should be selected.

Or did I understood you correctly? Check either Hammer.js or FT's Fastclick for reference.

Comment: @zvona Thank you! I will check and report have I fixed this.